# open files that not in current folder- MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dialog, box

I want to open some file any file without knowing the name before in dialog box in MATLAB,
and i try to do

`filename =uigetfile;`

But i don't want to choose file just from the current folder.

I want to choose file from any place that i want on the computer.

Please help.

Comment: Look into its [doc](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) for `defaultname`. Take it from there.

Comment: But i want to choose the direction in the moment. I do not want to decide in advance which location to choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use uigetfile pointing to the root directory and the user can find the file from there e.g. on Mac and Linux

```
filename=uigetfile "/";
```

or on Windows:

```
filename=uigetfile "C:\";
```

You may want to point to "~/" on Mac and Linux rather than the root dir

Comment: :/, Unfortunately it is the same error. "The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path."

Comment: Sorry, I only have octave on my laptop atm and it works there but this may be a difference between it and MATLAB. Apologies I can't help more. From a bit of googling it looks like you'll need to add folders to the search path, possibly adding the root directory to it would work but I imagine they limit it for a reason.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to the file from the second output of `uigetfile` and functions like `open`, `run` or `matfile` (and most other file accessing functions) can work with a full path to a file outside of the Matlab path / current directory.

```
[fileName,filePath] = uigetfile;
```

The name and path can then be concatenated (the path will already end with the file separator but just to be sure `fullfile` can be used)

```
pathToFile = fullfile(filePath,fileName);
```

and passed to the required function;

```
open(pathToFile);
```